# javafx keyboard event shortcut key

Tags: javafx, keycode

I want to add keyboard shortcut key in javafx.

i have scene and want to implement the keyboard shortcut

my code is as follows

```
getApplication().getScene().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ke.getCode());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: my scene is getApplication().getScene() and i am not getting key event in this

Comment: What is `getApplication()` doing ? Is it returning an instance of your Application ? Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) depicting your problem ?

Comment: Are you looking for a global shortcut key (a key that works in all locations in your application) or a key that operates in a narrower scope?

Comment: yes i am looking for that kind of shortcut key

Answer (score 23):

Events travel from the scene to the focused node (event capturing) and then back to the scene (event bubbling). Event filter are triggered during event capturing, while onKeyPressed and event handler are triggered during event bubbling. Some controls (for example TextField) consume the event, so it never comes back to the scene, i.e. event bubbling is canceled and onKeyPressed for the scene doesn't work.

To get **all** key pressed events use **addEventFilter** method:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ke.getCode());
            ke.consume(); // <-- stops passing the event to next node
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to capture **key combinations** use the **KeyCodeCombination** class:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    final KeyCombination keyComb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ESCAPE,
                                                          KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (keyComb.match(ke)) {
            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + keyComb);
            ke.consume(); // <-- stops passing the event to next node
        }
    }
});
```

There is also the possibility to add shortcuts to the menu by setting an accelerator (see [2]).

References

- [1] http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm
- [2] https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/tutorial-how-to-setup-key-combinations-in-javafx/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are doing with `getApplication`, but just to show that `KeyEventHandler` on `Scene` works, here's a demo for you.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label heading = new Label("Press Key");
        Label keyPressed = new Label();
        root.getChildren().addAll(heading, keyPressed);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                keyPressed.setText("Key Pressed: " + ke.getCode());
            }
        });

        stage.setTitle("My JavaFX Application");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the Scene of a controller either with giving it an `fx:id` or take a component of the scene of your choice and do `myComponent.getScene()`. Or you can set the `onKeyPressed` property/method/action of the scene in the fxml file (or via SceneBuilder).

Answer (score 1):

I just started learning javaFX so hope that help someone like me out there :)

Here is an example of key combination of how to exit from the app. You can perform any action you want.

1st, init a controller (could be a button or menu item)

```
MenuItem quit = new MenuItem("Quit");
```

2nd, set event handler

```
quit.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
   @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
     //  quit/close app
     primaryStage.close();
   }
});
```

and then setAccelerator to perform an action

```
quit.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.E, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
```

here is a detail tutorial

https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/tutorial-how-to-setup-key-combinations-in-javafx/

Hope that helps :)