# JavaFX - Accelerator not working when textfield has focus

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, accelerator

In my application I have a screen where I use Accelerators. I'm using the function key F3 to execute an operation in my application. It works fine everytime, but when I click in any TextField on this screen the function key doesn't execute.

Here is the code where I set the Accelerator:

```
    scene.getAccelerators().put(
            new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F3),
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do sth here
                }
            }
    );
```

When I click my textfield and then hit the F3 function key it doesn't work.
Someone knows the solution?

Comment: See this SO question for a better answer that doesn't require modifying the control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397742/javafx-keyboard-event-shortcut-key

Comment: seems to be fixed in fx9, that is accelerators (in menus and manually installed) are working if textField is focused

Answer (score 4):

This works for me using Java 1.8.0_45. However I encounter a similar issue with an editable Combobox field.

Edited:

Upon further investigation it does seem to occur with text field as well. I worked around it using the following custom class in place of text field:

```
public class ShortcutFriendlyTextField extends TextField{

    public ShortcutFriendlyTextField() {
        super();
        addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED,new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                //handle shortcuts if defined
                Runnable r=getScene().getAccelerators().get(new KeyCodeCombination(event.getCode()));
                if(r!=null) {
                    r.run();  
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [tikerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851356/tkerman)'s. I added the code to handle modifier keys.

```
if (!event.getCode().isModifierKey()) {
    Consumer<KeyCombination.Modifier[]> runAccelerator = (modifiers) -> {
        Runnable r = getScene().getAccelerators().get(new KeyCodeCombination(event.getCode(), modifiers));
        if (r != null) {
            r.run();
        }
    };

    List<KeyCombination.Modifier> modifiers = new ArrayList<>();
    if (event.isControlDown()) modifiers.add(KeyCodeCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
    if (event.isShiftDown()) modifiers.add(KeyCodeCombination.SHIFT_DOWN);
    if (event.isAltDown()) modifiers.add(KeyCodeCombination.ALT_DOWN);

    runAccelerator.apply(modifiers.toArray(new KeyCombination.Modifier[modifiers.size()]));
}
```

Edit: fix consumer spelling.

Comment: This looks interesting, but is the code correct? The `modifier` variable seems to be used before defined? Also, what is the purpose of the code? Even with the simpler version my accelerators with modifiers seem to be working OK (tested with JavaFX 8).

Comment: I was wrong about modifiers - they are not handled well in the other code, the modifier key itself throws exception when attempting to handle its release. Still I am convinced the order of the code is wrong.

Comment: @Suma The first `modifier` variable is a parameter of a lambda expression. In other words, it is local to the runAccelerator object. It does not refer to the one define as a `List<KeyCombination.Modifier>`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have accelerators setup else where, such as a MenuBar, using some of the other solutions will cause the shortcut to be executed twice.

In my case, using modifiers with my shortcut (SHIFT + F3) works while in focus in the text area, but not while using just an accelerator such as just F3.

I set mine up to only use the event handler for shortcuts that do not use a modifier.

```
public  static final double JAVA_VERSION = Double.parseDouble(System.getProperty("java.specification.version"));
public static void makeInputFieldShortCutFriendly(Node node) {
    //this bug wasn't fixed until 9.0
    if (JAVA_VERSION < 9) {
        node.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent event) -> {
            if (!event.getCode().isModifierKey()) {
                if (!event.isAltDown() && !event.isShiftDown() && !event.isAltDown()) {
                    Runnable r = node.getScene().getAccelerators().get(new KeyCodeCombination(event.getCode(), KeyCodeCombination.SHORTCUT_ANY));

                    if (r != null) {
                        r.run();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: No modifier shortcuts was fixed in Java 9. Given the popularity of JDK 8 right now, we should probably provide some backwards capatability or request users update there JRE to 9+.

Comment: the problem seems to be fixed in fx9, that is accelerators (in menus and manually installed) are working if textField is focused

Answer (score -1):

I you are using JavaFx+Scene builder then just make a function that redirect all the event to the respective functions and then add this function to every element in the scene with OnKeyReleased event