# how to use key on pressed in java FXML?I want to use shortcut keys to do button action

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I want to use shortcut keys to do action.

```
<Button layoutX="554.0" layoutY="411.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#edit" onKeyPressed="#edit_key" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Edit" />
```

FXML code

```
@FXML
private void edit_key(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        //to do button action               
        }

}
```

Comment: I've absolutely no clue what exactly you're asking about. Is it how to progammatically trigger an `onAction` event for the button from the event handler method? For the *enter* key this should already be implemented (assuming it's the button that's focused)...

Comment: I want to use the keyboard to control

Comment: See [this](https://medium.com/@zoha131/handling-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javafx-2972ba950a48) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397742/javafx-keyboard-event-shortcut-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is and example to capture a Key Press on a modal form
In the FXML Editor under the Code section set onKeyPressed="#onPress" our base container is an Anchor Pane. Now in the Controller Class for that Anchor Pane use this method

```
    @FXML
private void onPress(KeyEvent ev) throws IOException{
    kc = ev.getCode();
    if(kc == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
        strTRANSFER = txtEnterValue.getText();
        onBack();
    }   
}
```

You can use what ever KeyCode you like